# aws efs describe-access-points no filters?

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-efs

When I run

```
aws efs describe-access-points --query 'AccessPoints[*].[AccessPointId]' --output table
```

I get back 5 different ID's.

There does not appear to be any filter options like there are for other resources.

```
aws efs describe-access-points --filters "Name=AccessPoints.Name,Values=media" --query 'AccessPoints[*].[AccessPointId]' --output table

usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:
  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
Unknown options: --filters, Name=AccessPoints.Name,Values=media
```

How can I return just the ID of my media access point?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the access point of a particular file system if

aws efs describe-access-points —-file-system-id  —-query “AccessPoints[].{AccessPointId:AccessPointId}” —-region=“”